# Why do I have to re-install MSMQ when I come off and back on to the office network?

Tags: msmq, windows-vista

I've got a really frustrating problem with MSMQ constantly refusing to work even though it's installed and started.

I have MSMQ installed on my Vista Business laptop (MSMQ-Container;MSMQ-Server;MSMQ-Triggers;MSMQ-DCOMProxy) and this laptop is joined to the company domain. Registry shows that it's installed under Workgroup mode which is fine by me as I only want to use direct connections to private queues (using a full FormatName (TCP based)) and could care less about AD integration.

When plugged into the office network all is well.

When I unplug and go home to work, MSMQ appears to be running (the service still runs) but all my attempts to connect to a queue fail with a "Service is Unavailable" exception. Tried with my .NET app, COM, QueueExplorer app and all say the same. Also the MSMQ stuff in Computer Management is gone.

The only way to get it back and working at home is to uninstall everything, and re-install it.

Then when I get to the office, I have to uninstall MSMQ and re-install for it to work when plugged into the office network!

Anyone got any ideas? I had a thought that maybe this has something to do with NICs and IP addresses changing etc? MSMQ seems to be really flakey at the moment.

Thanks!

Comment: I guess no-one has had this problem before..

I've trying adding the following DWORD to the registry to see if I can make this thing stay installed/working when I switch networks.

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSMQ\Parameters\Setup::AlwaysWithoutDS

Comment: Nope - to this day I've not been able to figure this out. I'm hoping it was just a problem with my work machine.

Comment: Do you have the Windows Firewall installed and does it have different rules for your home and office networks?

Comment: No, no firewall. I turned it off as part of my initial investigation. It made no difference.

Answer (score 0):

I recall running into that error (Service is unavailable/Waiting to connect) quite a few times when I was using MSMQ, and usually it would work after I restart both the client and server machines. Turns out that this was a MSMQ server bug, I managed to get everything working by installing [this Microsoft hotfix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2554746), though I don't know if they've put the hotfix in as part of windows updates now, but it's wortha try. Debugging MSMQ can drive you nuts, from my experience you should do a brute force try every suggested fix, no matter how ludicrous and far fetched they might seem initially.

There is a list of Microsoft MSMQ hotfixes [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/johnbreakwell/archive/2009/04/03/finding-the-latest-versions-of-msmq-to-install.aspx), though it's pretty outdated.